# C# Selenium WebDriver Foreach not working

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

This is my code in C# I press the delete button and open a pop up where I select the amount of deletions that I want to delete and press again on delete it will delete.

```
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Delete")).Click();
new SelectElement(PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//select[@id='remove_shares'])[2]"))).SelectByText("1");
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).Click();
```

---

What I'm trying to do is record a loop every time I press delete and open a pop-up window, find the highest value inside the dropdown and select it and delete.

But just every time the values inside the dropdown are changed:

```
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Delete")).Click();
var mySelectElm = PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//select[@id='remove_shares'])[2]"));
var mySelect = new SelectElement(mySelectElm);
var values = mySelect.SelectedOption;
foreach (var option in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(option.Text); //Prints "Option", followed by "Not Option"
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).Click();
 }
```

---

That the error I get but I need help with writing the code better:

> Error 1
>
> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' because
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' does not contain a public definition
>   for 'GetEnumerator'
>
> C:\Users\Numg\Desktop\selenium\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\Program.cs 54  17  ConsoleApplication5

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
var values = mySelect.SelectedOption;
```

With this:

```
var values = mySelect.Options;
```

That way your `foreach` loop will work, because you'll have a list of options to loop through. Your current code only returns a single element, on which `foreach` does not work.

Comment: when i changed to  var values = mySelect.Otions; get error message Error 1 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement' does not contain a definition for 'Otions' and no extension method 'Otions' accepting a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Numg\Desktop\selenium\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\Program.cs 53 39 ConsoleApplication5

Comment: Really you didnt notice the spelling error? and the missing p... lol

Comment: sorry my bud,but now i get error message Test Name: ADDITEMTOCART
Test Outcome: Failed
Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element <a class="button delete-share" data-id="delete-0">...</a> is not clickable at point (921, 539). Other element would receive the click: <span>...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
Result StandardOutput: 
opened url
close the broswer